# How to change the button text in Rails 4?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

How Do you change the text of the submit button in Ruby on Rails ? I have tried adding the label method but it won't work.

**/_form.html.erb**

```
  <div class="form-group">
    <%= f.submit class: "btn btn-primary" , label: "Click Here"%>
  </div>
```

Comment: From the api:  http://api.rubyonrails.org/: `submit(value=nil, options={})`: " When no value is given, it checks if the object is a new resource or not to create the proper label".  Granted, it doesn't specifically say that the "value" argument is used to set the "value" attribute in the submit tag, but you could at least try that before posting here.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

instead of using label use

```
<div class="form-group">
  <%= f.submit "Click Here", class: "btn btn-primary" %>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

You can give custom button name like:-

```
<%= f.submit 'custom_btn_name', class: "btn btn-primary" %>
```

Comment: "custom text" not custom "name". name is a http tag attribute would be part of the options hash as class is here.